# JHipster Spring startup failed with Logback configuration error

Tags: java, spring, logback, jhipster

I recently decided to give JHipster a try in the development of a new Java application. So far it has been fine, but following the creation of a few entities, I am now getting an IllegalStateException for "Logback configuration error detected".

```
2016-01-12 23:08:00.187 ERROR 5972 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - There is no conversion class registered for composite conversion word [clr]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - Failed to create converter for [%clr] keyword
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - There is no conversion class registered for composite conversion word [clr]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - Failed to create converter for [%clr] keyword
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - There is no conversion class registered for composite conversion word [clr]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - Failed to create converter for [%clr] keyword
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - There is no conversion class registered for composite conversion word [clr]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - Failed to create converter for [%clr] keyword
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - There is no conversion class registered for composite conversion word [clr]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - Failed to create converter for [%clr] keyword
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - There is no conversion class registered for composite conversion word [clr]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - Failed to create converter for [%clr] keyword
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - There is no conversion class registered for composite conversion word [clr]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - Failed to create converter for [%clr] keyword
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [wEx]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@30655222 - [wEx] is not a valid conversion word
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@7abf4b83 - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [wEx]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@7abf4b83 - [wEx] is not a valid conversion word
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:153) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:71) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:49) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:262) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:233) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:325) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.electom.higgler.Application.main(Application.java:74) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
```

Any assistance that may be rendered is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error says there is an error in your logback-spring.xml, compare its current contents with initial one after app generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your logback configuration has incorrect values. Specifically for the coloring feature of logback layouts.

I would refer to this posting and make sure you have the correct layout. Something like this perhaps:

```
public static final String CONSOLE_PATTERN =
    "%yellow(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS})"
```

Comment: PatternLayout recognizes "%black", "%red", "%green","%yellow","%blue", "%magenta","%cyan", "%white", "%gray", "%boldRed","%boldGreen", "%boldYellow", "%boldBlue", "%boldMagenta""%boldCyan", "%boldWhite" and "%highlight" as conversion words.
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html